# Writing to a file with stdio

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, stdio

I am using an example code from the wiringPi library to read data from Arduino to Raspberry Pi through serial, it is displaying the data correctly with `printf("%c", newChar);` but I can't write the same data to a text file.

This is the whole file:

```
 /*
 Pi_Serial_test.cpp - SerialProtocol library - demo
 Copyright (c) 2014 NicoHood.  All right reserved.
 Program to test serial communication

 Compile with:
 sudo gcc -o Pi_Serial_Test.o Pi_Serial_Test.cpp -lwiringPi -DRaspberryPi -pedantic -Wall
 sudo ./Pi_Serial_Test.o
 */

// just that the Arduino IDE doesnt compile these files.
#ifdef RaspberryPi

//include system librarys
#include <stdio.h> //for printf
#include <stdint.h> //uint8_t definitions
#include <stdlib.h> //for exit(int);
#include <string.h> //for errno
#include <errno.h> //error output

//wiring Pi
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

char device[]= "/dev/ttyAMA0";
// filedescriptor
int fd;
unsigned long baud = 9600;
unsigned long timeTemp=0;
unsigned long timeHum=0;
//unsigned long timeLight=0;
//unsigned long timeMotion=0;


//prototypes
int main(void);
void loop(void);
void setup(void);

void setup(){
  printf("%s \n", "Raspberry Startup!");
  fflush(stdout);

  //get filedescriptor
  if ((fd = serialOpen (device, baud)) < 0){
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    exit(1); //error
  }

  //setup GPIO in wiringPi mode
  if (wiringPiSetup () == -1){
    fprintf (stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    exit(1); //error
  }

}

void loop() {
  // Temperature every 3 seconds
  if(millis()-timeTemp>=3000){
    serialPuts (fd, "05\n");
    // you can also write data from 0-255
    // 65 is in ASCII 'A'
    //serialPutchar (fd, 5);
    timeTemp=millis();
  }

  // read signal
  if(serialDataAvail (fd)){
    char newChar = serialGetchar (fd);
    FILE * writeTemp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    printf("%c", newChar);
    fputc(newChar, writeTemp);
    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(writeTemp);
    }


// Humidity every 4 seconds
  if(millis()-timeHum>=4000){
    serialPuts (fd, "06\n");
    // you can also write data from 0-255
    // 65 is in ASCII 'A'
    //serialPutchar (fd, 5);
    timeHum=millis();
  }

  // read signal
  if(serialDataAvail (fd)){
    char newChar = serialGetchar (fd);
    //printf("received from ardiono \n");
    printf("%c", newChar);
    fflush(stdout);
    }



  }

// main function for normal c++ programs on Raspberry
int main(){
  setup();
  while(1) loop();
  return 0;
}

#endif //#ifdef RaspberryPi
```

I've tried different commands, but I'm constantly getting errors for invalid conversions from const char* to char or to FILE.

I just need to write the data from `printf("%c", newChar);` in a file.

Comment: Well... start here: fputc() takes a char as first parameter, not a pointer to it.  You don't check if the file opened OK. Other stuff.

Comment: I've tried fputc(newChar, writeTemp); but the text file stays or gets emptied. I edited the code to avoid further confusion. And I added `FILE * writeTemp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    if (writeTemp == NULL) {
    printf("cannot open file");
    exit(1);
}` but it doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `fputc(&newChar, writeTemp);`, you're taking a pointer to your character, converting it to `int`, then writing that to your file.  You should just write your character; something like `fputc(newChar, writeTemp);`.  Or `fprintf(writeTemp, "%c", newchar);` if you prefer printf.

Comment: I've tried it with fputc(newChar, writeTemp); and fprintf(writeTemp, "%c", newchar); but the text file stays empty or gets emptied after I run the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a printf-like function, use [`fprintf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm). 
To write your output to a file, you would write

```
 fprintf(writeTemp, "%c", newChar);
```

Also, the line

```
 char value = printf("%c", newChar);
```

does not make sense, since value is declared as a `char` but is assigned the return status from `printf`.

As another reply points out, the arguments to `fputc()` are also wrong. You can write

```
fputc(newChar, writeTemp);
```

Answer (score 0):

fputc takes a int, not an address. The problem that you are having is because you are passing the address of newChar. change the code to

```
fputc(newValue, tempFile);
```

and you should be good to go.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Using append instead of write somehow fixed the problem:

```
FILE * writeTemp = fopen("temp.txt", "a");
```

I also had to remove the second request:

```
    /*
// Humidity every 3 seconds
  if(millis()-timeHum>=3000){
    serialPuts (fd, "06\n");
    timeHum=millis();
  }

  // read signal
  if(serialDataAvail (fd)){
    char humChar = serialGetchar (fd);
    printf("%c", humChar);
    fflush(stdout);
    }
*/
```

because it was interfering with the data for some reason, even with different char variable.

Thank you for the answers.